# Why is my favicon not working on mobile? But works on Desktop?

Tags: html, favicon

This is the code I have for favicon, using node and express for the server and a simple index.html file, but I cannot see what I am doing wrong?

Why is the favicon working on desktop but not mobile?

Here is the code? Should I put this at the top of the head or does it not matter where in the head its put?

```
<!-- Favicons -->
<link rel="icon" href="/img/tb-fav-1.png" >
<link href="/img/tb-fav-1.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">
```

Comment: if the page is online you can check it thru something like https://www.validbot.com/tests/101/apple-touch-icon.html

Comment: Else I'd check if the files are reachable first, and if the sizes are correct.